# Sql 2005 triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers

can triggers be created in assemblies ?

Comment: why would you do such a thing is a completely different thing. CLR triggers are generally a bad idea. note that triggers are run inside a transaction and they could slow down everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create a .NET CLR trigger.

Answer (score 4):

[How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/938d9dz2(VS.80).aspx)